# Which is better Mysql vs Mysqli in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**which is better to use Mysql or Mysqli and in what conditions?**
I want to start a project that requires a database just wanted to know which of the two is better

Comment: It is _never_ better to use the `mysql_*` api over MySQLi unless you're on a version of PHP that's so old it is unavailable.

Comment: `Mysql` is deprecated and was removed in PHP7.

Comment: **Mysqli**. Cause **Mysql** extension is removed from latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use mysqli, the original mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5 ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php))

Comment: And removed in PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

> **MySQLi =>MySQL Improved**  With the Improved Suffix alone, you can guess which should be better using common sense. For more information [Read Up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi)